# Wrong date from timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, date, timestamp

```
<?php
    $z=$GLOBALS['argv'][1];
    $date=date('Y-m-d H:m:s',$z);
    echo $z."\n";
    echo $date."\n";
    echo strtotime($date)."\n";
?>
```

When I pass 1307433995 its ok

```
1307433995
2011-06-07 10:06:35
1307433995
```

but when I pass 1307436121 it`s something weird...

```
1307436121
2011-06-07 10:06:01
1307433961
```

Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Minutes is `i` not `m` in the [time formatting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Right code:

`<?php
    $z=$GLOBALS['argv'][1];
    $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$z);
    echo $z."\n";
    echo $date."\n";
    echo strtotime($date)."\n";
?>`

Comment: I think Java is more confusing in this area - it uses `M` and `m`! Also, if you are happy with the answer, please can you accept it (click the check mark just to the left)